# ctrl+c not killing a process

Tags: linux, bash, runit

I have a process that responds perfectly well to `CTRL+C` on my local machine.  And it appears to also be working.

But on an EC2 instance it freezes and becomes a defunct or zombie process.

`kill -9 <PID>` doesn't remove it and I have to reboot the EC2 instance to clean it up properly.

When it runs it also loads an in house developed shared library that I have no influence over and have no access to any source code in it to see what it's doing.  This library also uses CUDA and appears to start multiple threads.

I tried installing a signal handler on the main thread and it does get installed but calling `_exit` doesn't shut the whole process down, it seems to still be waiting.

Why might be happening here that is preventing `CTRL+C` from exiting the process cleanly?  Can I override or examine what the other threads could be doing?

Comment: Can you check with `ps -ly $PID` what does the column `S` (state) say? If it is `D`, then the process is in `uninterruptible sleep`.

Comment: Z.  Why would it not be being reaped, I kicked my process off from a shell interactively?

Comment: Is the shell still listed as the parent process? As a test could you try to send a SIGCHLD directly to the parent process to see if that will nudge it to reap?

Comment: What does `strace` show?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I found the problem.  I'll leave the question as it stands in case it helps someone else.

It turns out that on my PC, I have a GTX 680 and the drivers get installed when installing CUDA.  On EC2 the card is a GRID K520, and the driver installed by CUDA doesn't work.  I downloaded and installed the latest stable card specific driver and it then worked.

The discovery was made after running `nvidia-smi` and it wouldn't print any details about the card but rather would just show `Killed`. Run nvidia-smi again and it would lock up the console.

Unfortunately, I hadn't tested that CUDA app's were working but relied on the driver appearing to print a message in the log saying it was loaded and assumed it was working.

Updating the driver consisted of downloading the latest driver from nvidia (use the .run version).  Then:

```
sudo modprobe -r nvidia_uvm
sudo modprobe -r nvidia
```

Finally install it with a command like:

```
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-3xx.xx.xx.run
```

I then rebooted the instance and verified it with nvidia-smi

This link was insightful - [CUDA 7.5 unstable on EC2](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/880246/cuda-7-5-unstable-on-ec2-/)